# Does it mean to Show JSON String in jsp without JavaScript?

Tags: java, json, jsp

I have a JSON String like this as I write below. I Want to display it in jsp without any javascript or Jquery

```
{
    "menu": {
        "items": [
            {
                "id":"Open"
            }, {
                "id":"OpenNew",
                "label":"Open New"
            }
```

This is my JSP :

```
<form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Show" method="get">
    <ul id="list">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do another thing(using JSTL):

Map your  json string in a model class, set it to a Model. Then in JSP side, you access that model like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${modelClass.menu.items}" var="loop">
    <li>${loop.id}</li>
</c:forEach>
```

In your `controller`: 
Set `modelClass` ModelDTO where your `json` string values will be mapped.
Please let me know if this helps.